# Unable to stop ArcGIS Server automatic cache generation

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, tilecache, cache

I'm running ArcGIS Server 10.1 on a Windows box on Amazon, via remote desktop.

I've set up some services on which I have enabled caching using the Bing/Google/Esri scheme. I explicitly set these to Update Cache Manually.

[image]

For some reason, ArcGIS Server is changing these services to Update Cache Automatically. If I change it back to Manual, then immediately re-open the dialog, it has reverted to Automatic. If I choose View Cache Status, it's shown as "Tile Generation is in progress". Cancelling the tile generation has no effect - it immediately restarts.

I am creating these services by first creating *.sd files, in which I specify the cache levels and that I wish for Manual cache generation, then creating ArcGIS Server services from the *.sd files.

Why are these services changing irrevocably to Automatic cache updating?

Thanks

Comment: Is sp1 installed ?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has been asked some time ago, but just wanted to share what ESRI said about this if others run into this issue.  The "Automatic cache updating" radio button or honored when you are going through the publishing or re-publishing process.  If you don't want the server to cache your service automatically, just make sure the setting is set to manual each time you go through the publish process.

Comment: hmmm sounds awfully like a bug to me ;) FWIW I've since moved to ArcGIS Online so I'm not seeing this any more, and I can't verify whether it's been resolved

Comment: This appears to still be the case at 10.3.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting Status.gdb in \arcgisserver\arcgiscache\\Layers did the trick.